# What is the word for this definition?

Tags: vocabulary

In my country when two people want to get married they set an amount of money that if they want to get divorced the husband must give that money to his wife.
I wanted to know if there is any specific word for this money in English 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do couple set aside amount of money or just (husband) man?

Comment: It is Just husband

Comment: Normally, husband pays alimony, but it is not set aside before marriage. Whereas, you can use word "prenup" (prenuptial agreement), but again it is not specific to just money and it is gender neutral. You can have prenup agreement to share half of your property as well ( house, cart etc.) as well.

Comment: Since it’s something related to religion maybe in English we don’t have any specific word. Thanks anyway

Comment: When you say 'set' do you mean they literally set that sum of money aside in a bank account or lodged with the courts, or that they agree upon a sum, which does not necessarily represent money they currently posses.

Comment: There's a similar *idea* in the engagement ring. At one point in the past it was a sort of "insurance" for the woman. Should the man break off the engagement, her reputation would be sullied and her marriage prospects reduced, but at least she'd have a little compensation in the form of the engagement ring. Now, of course, men can have engagement rings, too! I've heard of the arrangement in the question and the non-native speaker referred to it as a sort of "dowry", but I don't think this is quite the correct term. The woman only gets if they get divorced.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers I think the word alimony was the best I can use

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a word for the sum of money itself. But a [prenuptial agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenuptial_agreement) (or *prenup* informally) is a legal agreement entered into prior to marriage. It can specify how property is divided in the case of a divorce.